# Rendering different forms inside a form_for method in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, form-for

I have a form_for on a page in my rails app.  I want the user to be able to select the deal stage they want to input from a drop down menu, and for the page to respond with the corresponding form (which is in the corresponding partial).  Below is a simplified version of the form_for.  I also have javascript which hides the 4 partials when the page is loaded, and then when one is selected from the select menu, shows that partial.

```
= form_for @activity do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :select_deal_stage
    = f.select(:deal_stage, DEAL_STAGE_ARRAY[], {:selected => nil, :prompt => 'Select Stage'})
  = render "deal_stage_1_partial", :f => f
  = render "deal_stage_2_partial", :f => f
  = render "deal_stage_3_partial", :f => f
  = render "deal_stage_4_partial", :f => f
```

The problem here appears to be that when I fill out and submit the form, the parameters are blank, presumably because the fields are repeated within the form_for and it is submitting values from the last fields or somehow submitting values from the fields that are not actually the ones that were filled out.  How can I get this to work, while having the deal_stage, which is selected from the drop down menu, be one of the parameters submitted with the form?

Additional Information:
The partials are all different but have some shared fields.  The params ends up being a full list of all the fields across all the forms.

Comment: Can you submit the content of the partials?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Name the four sets of duplicated fields differently, eg. if you have a item_no field, call it item_no_1, item_no_2, item_no_3, and item_no_4. Then deal with moving the correct one to item_no.
2. Render only one of the four views/partials at a time. That would imply that the user has to select the option before you render.

Good luck!